# FutureWarning in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample python code:

```
import pandas as pd
ddf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
                'Id' : [3,1,2],
                'col3': ['x','a','b']})
ddf.index=ddf['Id']
ddf.sort_values(by='Id')
```

The above snippet produces ' FutureWarning: 'Id' is both an index level and a column label. Defaulting to column, but this will raise an ambiguity error in a future version'. And it does become a error when I try this under recent version of python. I am quite new to python and pandas. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add  `.values`

```
ddf.index=ddf['Id'].values
ddf.sort_values(by='Id')
Out[314]: 
  col1  Id col3
1    A   1    a
2    B   2    b
3    A   3    x
```

Comment: Accepting this as answer since I chose to do this. But jezrael's response is very detailed and educational

Answer (score 4):

Here the best is convert column `Id` to `index` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for avoid `index.name` same with one of columns name:

```
ddf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
                'Id' : [3,1,2],
                'col3': ['x','a','b']})
ddf = ddf.set_index('Id')

print (ddf.index.name)
Id
print (ddf.columns)
Index(['col1', 'col3'], dtype='object')
```

Better for sorting by index is [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
print (ddf.sort_index())
   col1 col3
Id          
1     A    a
2     B    b
3     A    x
```

Your solution working, if change `index.name` for different:

```
ddf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
                'Id' : [3,1,2],
                'col3': ['x','a','b']})
ddf.index=ddf['Id']
```

---

```
print (ddf.index.name)
Id
print (ddf.columns)
Index(['col1', 'Id', 'col3'], dtype='object')
```

Set different `index.name` by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) or set by scalar:

```
ddf = ddf.rename_axis('newID')
#alternative
#ddf.index.name = 'newID' 

print (ddf.index.name)
newID
print (ddf.columns)
Index(['col1', 'Id', 'col3'], dtype='object')
```

So now is possible distinguish between index level and columns names, because `sort_values` working with both:

```
print(ddf.sort_values(by='Id'))
      col1  Id col3
newID              
1        A   1    a
2        B   2    b
3        A   3    x

print (ddf.sort_values(by='newID'))
#same like sorting by index
#print (ddf.sort_index())
      col1  Id col3
newID              
1        A   1    a
2        B   2    b
3        A   3    x
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your columns and row index contain 'Id', a simple solution would be to not set the (row) index as 'Id'.

```
import pandas as pd
ddf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
                    'Id' : [3,1,2],
                    'col3': ['x','a','b']})
ddf.sort_values(by='Id')
Out[0]: 
  col1  Id col3
1    A   1    a
2    B   2    b
0    A   3    x
```

Or set the index when you create the df:

```
ddf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
                    'col3': ['x','a','b']}, 
                   index=[3,1,2])
ddf.sort_index()
Out[1]: 
  col1 col3
1    A    a
2    B    b
3    A    x
```